# SSMA for Oracle - Getting "No such host is known" when connecting to Azure SQL

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database, sql-server-migration-assi

I am trying to use SSMA to migrate data from Oracle to Azure SQL Server.  I have everything installed, and successfully completed the steps for converting the Schema.  All 145 tables have been successfully created in Azure SQL.

I have successfully connected to Oracle and Azure, and can expand the objects in both Metadata Explorer windows no problem.

When I try to do the "Migrate Data" step, it prompts me to enter the login credentials again for both connections, then it keeps reporting this error:

Migrating data...
Analyzing metadata...
Preparing table AMDS.AIRPORT...
Preparing data migration package...
Starting data migration Engine
Starting data migration...
**Exception during processing: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)**
Data migration operation has finished.
0 table(s) successfully migrated.
0 table(s) partially migrated.
1 table(s) failed to migrate.

I have re-tried several times, including selecting just one table as in the example above, but I keep getting the same "error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server".

I am using the latest version of SSMA for Oracle, 8.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string, make sure while migrating, your target server name
is not  tcp:{servername}, {port} instead just give {servername}.

Comment: Wow, that worked.  Thank you so much!  I don't think I ever would have thought of that.